# Google Drive API: 404 when accessing file someone else created

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I'm trying to get the contents of a file located a shared drive in which I am a content manager. The scope I'm using is https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file.
I get 404 errors when I try to access files that are created with my app (which I know is required for the drive.file scope), but *by someone else*. Everything works as it should when I try to access files created by me.
Here is my code:

```
function getJsonContent(fileId, accessToken) { 
    let url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + fileId + "?alt=media&supportsAllDrives=true"; 
    console.log("Sending JSON read request.");
    
    return fetch(url, { 
        'headers': {'Authorization': "Bearer " + accessToken}
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            console.log("JSON read successful.");
            return response.json();
        }
        else {
            throw "JSON read unsuccessful."; 
        }
    }); 
}
```

Here is my authorization code:

```
function handleAuth(onAccept, onDenial) {

    let onSignInUpdate = function(isSignedIn) { 
        if (isSignedIn) {
            onAccept(); 
        } else {
            onDenial();
        }
    }

    gapi.load('client:auth2', function() { 
        gapi.client.init({
            apiKey: API_KEY,
            clientId: CLIENT_ID,
            discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
            scope: SCOPES
        })
        .then(function() {
            gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(onSignInUpdate);
            onSignInUpdate(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get()); //Initial update
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        });
    });
}

//In another module, specific to a webpage:

function onAccept() { 
    accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token; 
    
    getJsonContent(<ACTUALFILEID>, accessToken)
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
}

function onDenial() {
    console.log("Permission rejected; redirecting to index.html.");
    location.replace("index.html");
}

window.onload = function() {
    handleAuth(onAccept, onDenial);
};
```

This is the file creation code:

```
function makeJsonFile(parentId, fileName, accessToken) { 
    let url = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart&fields=id&keepRevisionForever=true&supportsAllDrives=true"; 
    console.log("Sending JSON creation request.");

    let file = new Blob([JSON.stringify([])], {'type': "application/json"}); //The object is an empty array initially
    let metadata = {
        'name': fileName,
        'mimeType': "application/json",
        'parents': [parentId],
    }

    let form = new FormData();
    form.append("metadata", new Blob([JSON.stringify(metadata)], {type: "application/json"})); 
    form.append("file", file); 

    return fetch(url, { //Returns a promise that resolves with the id of the created file
        'method': "POST", 
        'headers': { 
            'Authorization': "Bearer " + accessToken
        },
        'body': form  
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            console.log("JSON created.")
            return response.json(); 
        }
        else {
            throw "JSON creation unsuccessful."; 
        }
    })
    .then(val => val.id);
}
```

Comment: please edit your question and inlcude your authorization code.  If its on a shaired drive you also need to add the teamsdriveid

Comment: @DaImTo I've added the authorization code. I've never done anything to include a teamsdriveid anywhere, so that might be the problem. But to be clear: I can access files on my shared drive, without specifying the teamsdriveid anywhere, as long as I am the creator of the files I'm trying to access.

Comment: Could you provide the code related to the file creation? Also, can you provide the full error message you're getting?

Comment: @Iamblichus Good point, I've added it now. As you've probably noticed already, I'm using fetch with an accessToken instead of the "drive.files.create" method from the API, as I found examples using fetch easier to understand. The error message I'm getting from getJsonContent is "GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1ubVdAXHSgywx-BnEtAZCIk5tKwni9jyd?alt=media&supportsAllDrives=true 404".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

**`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` only gives you access to files that YOU have opened or created with the corresponding app**. See [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#drive):

> View and manage Google Drive files and folders that **you have opened or created** with this app.

In this case, it is irrelevant that the file is created on a shared drive. I'm thinking you will have to use a wider scope like `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`, unfortunately.

#### Feature request:

Also, considering your situation, I think you might be interested in this Feature Request, regarding the possibility to restrict access to a specific folder. I think that could be very useful for you if it got implemented. I'd suggest you to star that issue, both to keep track of its development and to help prioritize its implemenation:

- [Drive Restrict access to folder when authorizing applications](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760598)

#### Reference:

- [OAuth 2.0 Scopes for Google APIs > Drive API, v3](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#drive)
- [Authorizing requests with OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth#OAuth2Authorizing)

Comment: Thank you! That feature request would indeed be perfect for my app.

Comment: This is very frustrating. Google has been pushing to move to the 'drive.file' scope but not being able to view files that other people have uploaded (via our app) to a folder that the our app has created is super limiting. I don't understand why they would prevent that, the drive.file scope should allow to view all files created by the app and not only by the current user.