# Google Drive API behaviour for shared folders using the drive.file scope

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive, google-drive-picker

We have an application where we are trying to use the less sensitive drive.file scope but we are running into an issue: Say that there are 2 different users, User A, creates a folder from within our app (using the Drive API and the drive.file scope) and then shares that folder with User B also within our app using the permissions API. Then User B uploads a file to that shared folder (again, using our app with the same client id). The issue is that User A cannot see the files that User B has uploaded even though he has access to that folder (he created it) and the files were uploaded from our app (same app id / key).

From our understanding, when using the **drive.file scope our app should be able to view the files created by our own app**. In the example above the files are uploaded to a folder that both users have access to and they have been created via our app, why would User A don't see the new files when listing the contents of the folder?

Can someone at Google clarify this behaviour? I really hope this is a bug and can be fixed.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: 1) We need more details on what was uploaded, file permissions and ownership, the identity used by your app, etc. Provide details so that anyone can reproduce your problem. 2) I doubt you have uncovered a bug. If it is a bug you have posted at the wrong place. Post at Google's [Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker).

Comment: I think what was uploaded is irrelevant but basically they are simple JPG images. Doing further research I found this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62776810/250307 that unfortunately confirms what I was afraid of: The drive.file scope allows to view files that the same user created despite being created from the exact same app and even when the user has access to the files. In other words the drive.file scope is not sufficient for collaborative apps which is a shame since Google is pushing us away from using the drive scope